# VBA - code for hiding rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet where if the value of a cell is Active, the row stays. If the value of the cell is inactive, the row gets hidden.  Any advice?

I have Excel 2016.

Comment: Auto-Filter (on the Data pane) then select that column and filter to keep only "Active"? Or do I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: I do not want to use the filter.  I want to be able to automatically hide the rows not needed or press a button.

Comment: unclear.....do you want to test a specific cell or any cell in a given column or any cell in the worksheet??

Comment: will the cell value be the result of a formula or a typed value??

Comment: I have rows that from a drop down list that will state inactive of active.  When Inactive is selected, I would like the row to be hidden, not deleted.  Ideally, the row will hide automatically, but i'm not sure if that is possible.

Comment: So you want to attach some code to that drop down list control which would hide the row where the drop down list is? Then copying those controls (and the attached code) all over the work sheet?

Comment: I'm not sure, I didn't know that was a possibility. I'm trying to make the spreadsheet as simple as possible without extra steps of using the filters.  I used to code 20+ years ago, apparently forgot the basis steps.  I've been trying to research and not finding what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following Event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If LCase(Target.Value) = "inactive" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

If a cell becomes "inactive", its row will be hidden.  *(The user can always undo this manually.)*

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**